# The number of subfield $K$ of $L$ such that $\,\mathbb{Q}\subsetneq K\subsetneq L$

Tags: field-theory

$\omega\neq 1 \in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\omega^3=1$, suppose $L$ be the field generated by $\omega, 2^{1/3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e $L=\mathbb{Q}, (\omega,2^{1/3})$, the number of subfields $K$ of $L$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\subsetneq K\subsetneq L$ is which integer?
Could any one tell me how to proceed?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you learned the galois theory?And what have you tried? Thanks.

Comment: No I did not learn Field theory too much and never learned galois theory :'( :(

Comment: Thus a question arises: how did you see this question? And what are your thoughts? These might help others understand where you are stuck. Regards.

Comment: It came to an entrance test paper as I was trying to solve all the questions so I thought I can tackle it by my known algebra knowledge which seems to be very insufficient to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;[\,\Bbb Q(w,\sqrt[3]2),\Bbb Q\,]=[\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2,w):\Bbb Q(w)\,][\,\Bbb 
Q(w):\Bbb Q\,]$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;x^2+2+1\in\Bbb Q[x]\;\;\text{is an irreducible polynomial }$$

$$(3)\;\;\;\;\text{There are only two groups of order $\,6\,$ up to isomorphism:$\\$ one has $\,3\,$ proper non-trivial subgroups, the other one has $\,4\,$ proper non-trivial subgroups}$$

**Added:** As the OP answered a comment saying (s)he hasn't studied any Galois Theory, we can try to following approach:

From $\;(1)-(2)\;$ we must be able to gather $\,\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2\,,\,w)=6\,$ , and from basic linear algebra we then know that for any $\,\Bbb Q\lneq K\lneq L \,$ we have to have $\,\dim_{\Bbb Q}K=2\,\vee\,3\,$ .

In order to find all the subfields of $\,L\,$ of  dimensions $\,2\,,\,3\,$ we could also use the fact that $\,\{\,1\,,\,\sqrt[3]2\,,\,\sqrt[3]4\,,\,w\,,\,w\sqrt[3]2\,,\,w\sqrt[3]4\,\}\;$ is a basis of $\,L_{\Bbb Q}\,$ , and then from here try to find minimal polynomials that fit some of these elements.

For example, $\,x^3-4\in\Bbb Q[x]\,$ is irreducible (why? You can't use Eisenstein...) , so that $\,[\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]4\,:\,\Bbb Q\,]=3\,$ and clearly $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]4)\le L\,$ ...

Comment: This approach seems to proceed using galois theory. As OP says he/she has never studied galois theory, I think that modifications are necessary. Regards.

Comment: Hmmm...I wrote my answer before the OP answered back that comment, but then it seems it is going to be a looooooong way to reach a more or less satisfactory result. I'll try to come up with a more basic-approach edit. Thanks.

Comment: It is indeed a long way to go, if we start from field theory only. But I think that there shouild be a more elementary way, as this is found in the context of a test. Also, thanks for addressing my comment.:D

Comment: Thanks @awllower. About that test it is said it was an *entrance test* , so either the OP was suposed to know this or else it was a classifying test, to know what the actual level of each participant is. I'm almost sure this question was aimed to people knowing *at least* some basic Galois Theory...at least about groups of automorphisms and stuff, say, but of course: I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the added version: it is much more elementary, and requires more calculations, as is ordinary: concepts are in exchange of computations. In any case, thanks for the good answer.

Comment: In above listed intermediate fields, Some of the field will be same(coincide),Actually, This G(L/Q) is isomorphic to S3 and has 4 subgroups So  answer is 4, am I correct